# JS (или jQuery) как добавить функцию в div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Написала такую функцию

```
var arr = [[1,2],[3,4]]
function tableEditor(someId, arr){
var string = "<table>";
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    string += "<tr>";
        for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            string += "<td>"  + arr[i][j] + " </td>" ;
        }
    string += "</tr>";
    } 
    string  +="</table>";
    document.write(string);
   }
tableEditor('someId', arr);
```

Как теперь мне ее добавить в div? div создан в HTML. Думала что то типа `$("div").append($(tableEditor))`, но это не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так, вместо document.write(string);:

```
   var div = document.getElementById(someId);
       div.innerHTML += string;
```

string - Ваша строка.
someId - ID div-a, который Вы передаете tableEditor('someId', arr);

Comment: вот только `div.appendChild(string);` не сработает так как передается строка в данной ситуации, а `appendChild` хочет получить валидный dom-элемент, созданый через `document.createElement`, в данной ситуации подойдет что-то типа `div.innerHTML += string;`

Comment: Да, простите, Вы правы. Сейчас поправлю.

Comment: Исправила код (свой div в HTML так и назвала div id="someId") :     
 var arr = [[1,2],[3,4]]
function tableEditor(someId, arr){
var string = "<table>";
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    string += "<tr>";
        for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        string += "<td>"  + arr[i][j] + " </td>" ;
              }
    string += "</tr>";
  } 
  string  +="</table>";
  var div = document.getElementById("someId");
       div.innerHTML += string;
}
tableEditor('someId', arr); Но выдает ошибку в консоле: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: @ЕленаЛещенко Так все получилось у Вас?

Comment: Igor. большое спасибо! все получилось!!

Comment: @ЕленаЛещенко А цифры появляются? Если появляются, просмотрите на код в браузере через инструменты разработчика. Вполне возможно, что таблица там есть, но стилей никаких у нее нет. Можете попробовать задать стили td, th {
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

Comment: да, видимо что-то не сохранила после редактирования и выдавало ошибку. Сохранила все файлы заново и всё заработало!

Answer (score 4):

В вашем коде `document.write(string);` заменяет все содержимое страницы на html из `string`. Замените эту строчку на `return string;` и тогда можно будет вставлять сгенерированный html в любой элемент, например, так `$("#block").append(tableEditor(arr))`.

Кстати, непонятно, для чего нужен аргумент `someId`, если в функции он не используется, поэтому я его убрал.

```js
var arr = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4]
]

function tableEditor(arr) {
  var string = "<table>";
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    string += "<tr>";
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      string += "<td>" + arr[i][j] + " </td>";
    }
    string += "</tr>";
  }
  string += "</table>";
  return string;
}
$("#block").append(tableEditor(arr));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block"></div>
```

Comment: Cheg, спасибо! так работает, если удалить аргумент someId, но я не сразу поняла, что мне нужно именно someId сделать! нужно чтобы таблица строилась в определенном диве с айдишником "someId"

Comment: @ЕленаЛещенко ну так код `$(selector).append(tableEditor(arr));` и так выстроит таблицу в диве с необходимым вам `id`. В моем примере это будет див с `id="block"`

Comment: Раз Вы используете jquery то в функции собирайте таблицу через jquery тоже, удобнее будет чем делать конкатенацию строк.

Comment: @АбрамовАлексей функцию не я писал

Comment: @Cheg Это так, общее замечание, наверно больше к автору направлено, в решении думаю было бы полезно предложить такой вариант. Функция мелкая, можно быстро подписать. Кстати, не знаю, автор вопроса получает уведомление в таком случае, если писать комментарий к ответу не указывая имя автора вопроса?

Comment: _В вашем коде document.write(string); заменяет все содержимое страницы на html из string._ - зависит от того, когда вызывается эта функция

Answer (score 0):

Еще предлагаю переделать функцию.

При конкатенации строки можно на ошибки наткнуться, так как нет проверки на значение вставляемое, например там может быть символ открывающаяся скобка **"<"** и тогда вся верстка поплывет.

```js
var arr = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4]
]

function tableEditor(arr) {
  var table = $("<table />");
  arr.forEach(function(row){
    var tr = $("<tr />");
    row.forEach(function(column){
      tr.append( $("<td />").html(column) );
    })
    table.append(tr);
  })
  
  return table;
}
$("#block").append(tableEditor(arr));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block"></div>
```

Comment: Тогда уж вместо forEach лучше использовать reduce

Comment: @Grundy Это уже слишком сложно, да и эта функция немного для другого предназначена, в этой функции производятся промежуточные вычисления. Напишите свой вариант с использованием этой функции, хотелось бы посмотреть преимущества.

Comment: На самом деле не сложнее, чем у тебя, просто используются более подходящие (по смыслу) функции, и нет лишних переменных: https://jsfiddle.net/7vjw4z9v/

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо! Для себя пометил такой вариант. Но, для начинающих думаю все же он сложнее для понимания как оно работает. Там кстати второй return лишний )

Comment: да, не убрал лишнее :)